# WFS-T Library in C++

Tags: software-recommendations, c++, wfs-t

Is there are a library open source that supports WFS-T requests and posts ?

I'm looking for an open source library that supports WFS/and WFS/T that works with open scene graph.

Comment: Have you checked GDAL http://www.gdal.org/drv_wfs.html? However, if you are not only experimenting you will probably want to have user rights management, some method for handling concurrent edits etc. GDAL can't help you with those. Actually neither does the WFS standard except concept of locking and even that is more like a prototype.

Comment: Are you trying to call an existing WFS-T service (i.e. are looking for a client side library), or are you trying to implement a WFS-T service (i.e. a server side library)? Also, is C++ a hard requirement, or is something callable from C++ suitable?

Comment: @BradHards Yes I'm trying to look for a client side library